# Get Asset Name from Texture2D in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to serialize data in my XNA project. I have a Texture2D background property that I use during runtime, but I also have a 'string property' to hold my Background name. This will allow me to serialize the asset name so I can later use the info to de-serialize later and load into my game.

Problem is myTexture.Name property is suppose to hold the Asset Name but when I try to serialize into an XML file, the BackgroundName Element is empty.

Here is what the Property code looks like:

```
//This property is Only used for serialization, myTexture is Texture2D and is assigned in the ctor of the class
public string BGName { get { return this.myTexture.Name;} set{/*Empty on purpose*/} }
```

Could someone please advise, how to retrieve the asset name from a Texture2D, according to MSDN, this field holds the name of the texture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Name` property on `GraphicsResource` isn't actually used by the XNA Framework; it's up to you to populate it with whatever you feel is appropriate.  You could write a helper method to do this easily enough:

```
public static Texture2D LoadTexture2D(this ContentManager content, String asset)
{
    var texture = content.Load<Texture2D>(asset);
    texture.Name = asset;
    return texture;
}

var texture = contentManager.LoadTexture2D("textures\\whatever");
Console.WriteLine(texture.Name); // should be "textures\\whatever"
```

Comment: OMG, only if MSDN would have just said exactly what you said on how to use the Name property of Texture2D, I would have been a happy camper 2 days ago. BTW, I was thinking of doing exactly the same thing to create a Texture2D and SpriteFont using a Utit class with static methods like the snippet you provided. A big muchas gracias to you sir for helping me out.

Comment: I agree that this is an unfortunate oversight.  As is often the case, I relied on the estimable Shawn Hargreaves to provide this information, who did so in a forum post.